# JQuery - Make entire div a link to different things depending on its class

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, hyperlink

new to Jquery, not rly understanding how to do arrays with it yet and I was wondering how to make a div into a link depending on its class, as well as make it link to different things depending on its class (example below).

css -

```
.a (link to domain.com/a)
.b (link to domain.com/b)
.c (link to domain.com/c)
```

HTML

```
<div class="a">
<div>
```

Comment: A div cannot be a link however you can apply click handlers and events to it depending on its class. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I guess so, I've tried the two answers below but can't seem to get them to work so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong on my part - I should mention I'm using the bootstrap custom of html5 boilerplate if it makes any difference and that the classes im trying to are the after version e.g. '.a:after'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little snippet will do it:

```
$(function () {
    $('div').each(function () {
        $(this).wrap('<a href="http://example.com/' + $(this).attr('class') + '" />');
    });
});
```

Demo on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/zkuFA/

What this does is uses the [jQuery wrap function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to add an `anchor` tag dynamically using the `classname` on the `div` for its `href` attribute

Comment: this sort of works but I'm not sure how to adapt it to only make divs with certain classes clickable as right now its making my whole page clickable

Comment: Ok update : got it to work on particular divs BUT now the issue is that it also plugs in all parent divs also, so it goes to example.com/parent child etc

Comment: I adapted this and got it to work how I want it to! I used the code below which may be crude but it did the job - $(function () {
    $('.a').each(function () {
        $(this).wrap('<a href="http://example.com/' + 'a' + '" />');
    });
});

Comment: Nice. Good to know it helped a little... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this:

```
$('.a').click(function(){
    window.location = "www.google.com";
});
$('.b').click(function(){
    window.location = "www.yahoo.com";
});
```

replace `www.google.com` and `www.yahoo.com` with your desired addresses for classes `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through `window.location.replace()` this way:

```
 $('.a').click(function(){
   window.location.replace('http://www.mysite.com/'+$(this).attr('class'));
   //---------> output url---> http://www.mysite.com/a
 });

 $('.b').click(function(){
   window.location.replace('http://www.mysite.com/'+$(this).attr('class'));
   //---------> output url---> http://www.mysite.com/b
 });
```

This will replace current document with the new one.